# Uniform convergence criterion

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I am having some difficulties to understand the formal criterion for uniform convergence. In the book *" Mathematics. It's content, methods and meaning"* I stumbled with the following series

$$ x + (x^2 - x) + (x^3 - x^2) + ..., $$

The n-th partial sum is then

$$ S_n(x) = x^n $$

and therefore

$$S(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty} S_n(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
      0 & 0\leq x < 1 \\
      1 & x = 1
\end{cases}$$

Intuitively I understand how this series would diverge at x = 1 as it would become a sum of infinite ones. Then the criteria for convergence indicates

$$\eta_n = \sup_{0 \leq x \leq 1} |S_n(x) - S(x)| = 1$$

since $\eta_n$ does not convergence to 0 as $ n \to \infty$ the series is not uniformly convergent. Two doubts:

- Why is not enough knowing that S(x) does not converge to 0 for all the range $(0, 1)$
- How is possible $\eta_n = 1$, why is not 0? as

$$S(x) = \sup_{0 \leq x \leq 1} |S_n(x) - S(x)| = 
\begin{cases} 
      |x^n - 0| & 0\leq x < 1 \\
      |x^n - 1| & x = 1
\end{cases}$$

so as to $n \to \infty$ $x=1$ then $|x^n - 1| = 0$

Comment: Note that the difference between any $S_n$ and $S$ starts off at $0$ at $x =0$, gets *arbitrarily close to* $1$ as you approach $x = 1$, and then drops off to $0$ again.

Comment: $S_n(x)$ *does* converge to $0$ for the range $(0,1)$. It just doesn't do so uniformly.

Comment: Also, the series doesn't diverge for $x=1$. It converges to $1$ as you've written. The parentheses are important.

Comment: bjorn93 is correct - the way this is written, the series is $$x + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (x^{n+1} - x^n)$$ When $x = 1$, every term of the infinite sum is $0$, which trivially converges to $0$.

Comment: AlexanderGeldhof When is it dropping off to 0? at x = 1?

Comment: PaulSinclair bjorn93 Yes, you are right it doesn't diverge at x=1 it converges to 1. So the convergence function is discontinuous, hence it is non-uniformly convergent. But I still do not understand why the supremum of $\eta_n$ is equal to 1 and not 0